# Python. Переменные в регулярных выражениях

Tags: python-3.5

Здравствуйте.
Есть некая регулярка, получающая данные из csv файла

```
f = open("file.txt", "r")
r = f.read()
price = re.findall(r"(\d+.\d+),.60005,", r)
f.close()
```

Файл после выгрузки содержит данные по нескольким складам. В данном примере номер склада 60005. Так же в программе имеется conf-файл в котором указаны пути, и т.д.

Т.к. нет возможности регулировать выгрузку по конкретным складам, пришла идея в conf-файле в переменную писать номер склада, а не менять номер непосредственно в коде. 
Но не могу понять как (и возможно ли?) подставить данные из переменной, как часть re запроса.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так:

```
f = open("file.txt", "r")
r = f.read()
sklad = "60005"
reg = r"(\d+.\d+),.{0},".format(sklad)
REG = re.compile(reg)
price = re.findall(REG, r)
f.close()
```